# Solr search keyword does not analyze for 2bytes and 1byte

Tags: solr

I'm use Solr 6.1

And I have problem below,

When Keyword is 2bytes(Keyword e.g. ａｐｔ) it will not get 1byte result(Keyword 
 e.g. apt)

how to fix it ?

Comment: sorry, i didn't get what is 2 bytes and 1 byte? it's about encoding?

Comment: So what is the analysis chain for the field? Are you doing anything to normalize the content?

Comment: @Mysterion Yes, "ａｐｔ" should be same "apt"

Comment: @MatsLindh the field type is string

Comment: Then no processing will take place, and the content you're indexing is the only way you'll be able to query it. You'll have to define an analysis chain with a TextField if you want Solr to process your text further.

Comment: @MatsLindh witch one I need define?
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory
and how to use it?

Comment: The ICU Normalizer or the ascii folding ones are possible candidates. A good starting point is the page for analyzers/filters/etc: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/understanding-analyzers-tokenizers-and-filters.html

Comment: I try to use the ICUNormalizer2CharFilterFactory but I get error =>
Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/charFilter "nfkc": Error loading class 'solr.ICUNormalizer2CharFilterFactory', That's possible because I'm not used cloud mode?